# How to assign different Joomla template styles to a category and it contains articles？

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

How to assign different Joomla template styles to a category and it contains articles, meaning that articles and categories use different style templates and layouts。
just like: 
Category A contains many A articles. This category uses the website template protostar, but the article I want to use beez3, is there a way to make a judgment to change the layout? Or directly assign different style templates?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla tends to be menu driven so you can create a Category Blog or Single Article menu option (page) or similar and then assign the required template style to each page in the template options.

Page classes can also be specified for menu options (pages) so that you can apply custom CSS to particular pages.